# How to update a column from a table base on another column's value from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have a `table A`, with 2 main columns: `Name` and `Settings`.
The `Settings` column will have 3 values: 1, 2 or 3.

For ex:

**table A**:

```
Name     Settings
Andre        1
Andre        1
Betty        3
Charles      1
Charles      1
```

Note that **1 `Name` can only have 1 `Settings`: 1, 2 or 3**.

I have another `table B`, with 2 main columns: `Name` and `Type`.
The `Type` column consists of many values, like: `'TypeA'`, `'TypeB'`, `'TypeC'`......

For ex:

**table B**:

```
Name       Type
Andre      TypeA
Andre      TypeA
Andre      TypeC
Betty      TypeB
Betty      TypeB
Betty      TypeD
Charles    TypeB
Charles    TypeA
Charles    TypeA
.....
```

Note that 1 `Name` can have multiple same or not same `Type`. **And we're just considering about `TypeA` and `TypeB`**.

Now I want to update the `Settings` column from `table A` using the `'Type'` column from `table B`, if:

- The `Type` column from `table B` is having the value of `'TypeA'`, then update all the records, which is having the same `Name` from both table, to 1 on the `Settings` column from `table A`.
- The `Type` column from `table B` is having the value of `'TypeB'`, then update all the records, which is having the same `Name` from both table, to 2 on the `Settings` column from `table A`.
- The `Type` column from `table B` is having both of the value of `'TypeA'` and `'TypeB'`, then update all the records, which is having the same `Name` from both table, to 3 on the `Settings` column from `table A`.

The result from `table A` should become like this:

```
Name     Settings
Andre        1
Andre        1
Andre        1
Betty        2
Charles      3
Charles      3
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that an aggregated correlated subquery might get the job done, like:

```
UPDATE ta
SET Settings = (
    SELECT
        CASE 
            WHEN MAX(tb.Type) = 'TypeA' AND MIN(tb.Type) = 'TypeA' THEN 1
            WHEN MAX(tb.Type) = 'TypeB' AND MIN(tb.Type) = 'TypeB' THEN 2
            ELSE 3
       END
    FROM TableB tb
    WHERE tb.Name = ta.Name AND Type in ('TypeA', 'TypeB')
    GROUP BY tb.Name
)
FROM TableA ta
```

In this **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=35c0e8a1aade1bb82ee3a2f8ee53889d)** with your sample data, here is the content of `TableA` after the `UPDATE` was executed:

```
Name    | Settings
:------ | -------:
Andre   |        1
Andre   |        1
Betty   |        2
Charles |        3
Charles |        3
```

Comment: Hi, I've tested it with my real data and it seems match with my expectation. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @VũTrần you should delete your other duplicate questions now because you've at last got what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

The update can join to a sub-query that counts those types per name for TableB.
Then the new "Settings" can be calculated based on those totals.

```
UPDATE a
SET a.Settings = (CASE
                  WHEN b.TotalTypeA > 0 AND b.TotalTypeB > 0 THEN 3
                  WHEN b.TotalTypeB > 0 THEN 2
                  WHEN b.TotalTypeA > 0 THEN 1
                  ELSE 0
                  END)
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT Name, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 'TypeA' THEN 1 END) TotalTypeA,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 'TypeB' THEN 1 END) TotalTypeB
  FROM TableB 
  GROUP BY Name
) b 
ON b.Name = a.Name;
```

A test on *RexTester* [here](https://rextester.com/EGDC70505)